# Copy radio value using its ID to insert into input as value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have some HTML code as follows:

```
<input name="bid" type="radio" value="1" id="1234"/>
<input name="bid" type="radio" value="2" id="5678"/>
<input type="text" id="paymount" name="paymount" value=""/>
```

Desired functionality:

When `radio=1` is checked, the `paymount` field value will show as `1234`. When `radio=2` is checked, the `paymount` field value will show as `5678`.

I have found posts on Stack Overflow, but a lot of them are related to hiding a text field.

Comment: you should consider using a different attribute than `id` for storing the value since `id` values starting with a number are prohibited: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id _web author must not use it to convey any information_

Comment: any other suggestion? thank you.

Comment: you could either use a semantic id, like `paymount-low` and `paymount-high` and use the `value` for the numbers, or you define an attribute like `data-paymount` and store the numbers there.

Comment: @Joshua Slight nit pick: [in HTML5 all-numeric IDs are valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<form name="radioForm">
    <input name="bid" type="radio" value="1" id="1234"/>
    <input name="bid" type="radio" value="2" id="5678"/>
    <input type="text" id="paymount" name="paymount" value=""/>
</form>     

<script type="text/javascript">
    var radio = document.radioForm.bid,
        input = document.getElementById('paymount');

    for(var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
        radio[i].onclick = function() {            
            input.value = this.id;
        };
    }
</script>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kison/zg5L5x8u/2/)

Comment: Hi, thank's for your awnser, but the `payment` `value` should be `radio` `id`, not `radio` `value` .

Answer (score 19):

Use change event handler for listening to the event.

```js
// use `[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[name="bid"]'))
// for older browser to covert NodeList to Array

// although check polyfill option of `ArrayforEach` for older browser
// or use simple `for` or `while` loop for iterating

// get all radio with the name,covert NodeList to array and iterate
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name="bid"]')).forEach(function(ele) {
  // add event handler to the element
  ele.addEventListener('change', function() {
    // update value of the input element
    document.getElementById('paymount').value = this.id;
    // if you are used `data-id="value" attribute instead of `id`
    // then get the value using `this.dataset.id`
  });
});
```

```html
<input name="bid" type="radio" value="1" id="1234" />
<input name="bid" type="radio" value="2" id="5678" />
<input type="text" id="paymount" name="paymount" value="" />
```

---

**FYI :** Use custom [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) for storing the corresponding value purpose of `id` attribute is for uniquely identifying an element. The custom  [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)  value can be retrieved from [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property of the element.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if this the best solution, but the following is working as you need.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="bid"]'),
    paymount = document.getElementById('paymount');

// loop over element, and add event listener
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener("change", onChange);
}
// callback 
function onChange(){
  paymount.value = this.id; // change paymount value to the selected radio id
}
```

```html
<input name="bid" type="radio" value="1" id="1234"/>
<input name="bid" type="radio" value="2" id="5678"/>
<input type="text" id="paymount" name="paymount" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    function getradio(i)
    {
        document.getElementById("paymount").value=i;
    }
</script>

<input name="bid" type="radio" value="1" id="1234" onclick="getradio(1234)"/>
<input name="bid" type="radio" value="2" id="5678" onclick="getradio(5678)"/>

<input type="text" id="paymount" name="paymount"/>
```

You can use JavaScript and call a function by using the onclick event on a radio button and pass the desired value.